# how to count the number of oids the snmp is dealing with

Tags: request, snmp

How to count the number of oids the snmp is dealing with? Some mibs provide the massage packets, but one massage packets could contain more than one oids request. I also want to know that how I should track the functions when I launch a snmpget request.

Answer (score 1):

First of all SNMP is not that simple!

**MIB** stands for Management Information Base and is a collection of information which is organized hierarchically. The various pieces of information are accessed by a protocol such as SNMP. There are two types of MIBs: scalar ones and tabular ones. Scalar objects define a single object instance whereas tabular objects define multiple related object instances grouped in MIB tables.

**OIDs** or Object Identifiers uniquely identify manged objects in an MIB hierarchy. It can be depicted as a tree whose nodes are assigned by different organizations. Generally, an OID is a long sequence of numbers, coding the nodes, separated by dots. Top level MIB object IDs (OIDs) belong to different standard organizations. Vendors define private branches including managed objects for their own products.

To make it even more simple MIBs are used to translate OIDs to human readable format. Like `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0` OID corresponds to:

```
Object Name:        sysDescr
Object Syntax:      DisplayString (OCTET STRING)
Display Hint:       255a
Object Access:      read-only
Object Status:      mandatory
Object Description:  A textual description of the entity. This value
             should include the full name and version
             identification of the system's hardware type,
             software operating-system, and networking
             software. It is mandatory that this only contain
             printable ASCII characters.
```

The other thing is SNMP PDU (Packet Data Unit) which is basically a data part of SNMP packet. It contains so called variable bindings (OID + Syntax + Value). There are no limitation on number of OIDs in SNMP PDU. So you can query as many as you want in single SNMP GET/GET-NEXT request.

Comment: Thanks for you attention. My problem is that :  snmp dealing with request needs time, i want to count the number that snmp is dealing with (agent part get the request but still not reponse, i want count how many oids in this part)